# Replace specific values in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How to replace particular values in Dataframe. For example in the below dataframe i  want to replace the rows starting with [AA,CB,EZ] and the value i want to replace is ''

```
   df = pandas.DataFrame({'A': ['AA','BB','CB','DD','EZ'],'B':[6,7,8,9,10],'C':[11,12,13,14,15]})
$ df
    A   B   C
 0  AA   6  11
 1  BB   7  12
 2  CB   8  13
 3  DD   9  14
 4  EZ  10  15

$ Expected Ouputdf
    A   B   C
 0  AA   
 1  BB   7  12
 2  CB     
 3  DD   9  14
 4  EZ
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can replace values by boolean mask by empty strings, but get mixed types - strings with numeric and some functions should failed:

```
mask = df['A'].str.startswith(('AA','CB','EZ'))

df.loc[mask, ['B', 'C']] = ''
print (df)
    A  B   C
0  AA       
1  BB  7  12
2  CB       
3  DD  9  14
4  EZ
```

Better is replace values to `NaN`s:

```
df.loc[mask, ['B', 'C']] = np.nan
print (df)
    A    B     C
0  AA  NaN   NaN
1  BB  7.0  12.0
2  CB  NaN   NaN
3  DD  9.0  14.0
4  EZ  NaN   NaN
```

Another solution:

```
df[['B', 'C']] = df[['B', 'C']].mask(mask)
```